# Tag assistant extension for AMP analytics

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html

- I tried to record a flow for my website using tag assistance extension, but it seems that it doesn't work with AMP analytics.
- Could anyone help me or suggest any similar tool to do this record.
- i'm trying to test if google analytics filter "to block our internal traffic" work or not. cause i tested it in google analytics and it seems that the traffic goes to the real time.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem
- we just need to send something like this

```
   <amp-analytics type="googleanalytics">
   <script type="application/json">
    {
     "vars": {
           "account": "UA-XXXXX-Y",
            "anonymizeIP": ""
      },
     "triggers": {
             "trackPageview": {
              "on": "visible",
              "request": "pageview"
          }
       }
    }
  </script>
 </amp-analytics>
```

-We should send "anonymizeIP": "" to make google pick up the user ip and then the filter will work.